# CompMgmtLauncher.exe. system error

Tags: windows-8.1

I bought a new Samsung laptop. It is showing CompMgmtLauncher.exe- system error

[image: image description here]

Answer (score 0):

The `commapi.dll` seams to be part of Broadcom Bluetooth driver (`C:\Program Files\bluetooth suite\commapi.dll`). Go to the samsung homepage, click on support, select your laptop model, download the bluetooth driver and reinstall the driver.